# Run ssh-add with Fabric in a machine

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm running some deployment tasks with Fabric that needs to checkout/update a Mercurial repository to the machine and then execute the appropriate copying/configuration.

Every time that I instatiate a new machine (we're currently using EC2 for our infrastructure) or when I run `hg pull` in the machine it'll ask for my ssh key passphrase, that's a bit annoying when we need to initialize a dozen machines at a time.

I've tried to run `ssh-add` in Fabric when the new EC2 instance is initialized but it seems like that `ssh-agent` isn't running for that shell and I get a `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` message from the output of Fabric.

How would I make `ssh-add` work when connected to the instance by the Fabric script?

Answer (score 3):

A [comment](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/72#issuecomment-1846470) on fabric's issue tracker solved this for me. It's a modified version of the [lincolnloop solution](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/22/easy-fabric-deployment-part-1-gitmercurial-and-ssh/). Using this "run" instead of fabric's will pipe your commands through ssh locally, allowing your local ssh-agent to provide the keys.

```
from fabric.api import env, roles, local, output
from fabric.operations import _shell_escape

def run(command, shell=True, pty=True):
    """
    Helper function.
    Runs a command with SSH agent forwarding enabled.

    Note:: Fabric (and paramiko) can't forward your SSH agent. 
    This helper uses your system's ssh to do so.
    """
    real_command = command
    if shell:
        cwd = env.get('cwd', '')
        if cwd:
            cwd = 'cd %s && ' % _shell_escape(cwd)
        real_command = '%s "%s"' % (env.shell,
            _shell_escape(cwd + real_command))
    if output.debug:
        print("[%s] run: %s" % (env.host_string, real_command))
    elif output.running:
        print("[%s] run: %s" % (env.host_string, command))
    local("ssh -A %s '%s'" % (env.host_string, real_command))
```

Please note that I'm running Fabric 1.3.2, and this fix won't be needed much longer.